# Can JS experts explain me this if conditional logic array reduce method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, reduce

**I'm not getting the logic written in if condition, I tried to console log the typeof acc, but it is undefined**

```
let people = [
  { name: 'Alice', age: 21 },
  { name: 'Max', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 20 }
];

function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
    let key = obj[property]
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = []
    }
    acc[key].push(obj)
    return acc
  }, {})
}

let groupedPeople = groupBy(people, 'age')
// groupedPeople is:
// {
//   20: [
//     { name: 'Max', age: 20 },
//     { name: 'Jane', age: 20 }
//   ],
//   21: [{ name: 'Alice', age: 21 }]
// }
```

Comment: "*I tried to console log the typeof acc*" - can you show us how, please? "*but it is undefined*" - no it's not

Comment: Are you asking about the `reduce` in general or just about the `if (!acc[key])` condition in particular?

Comment: @Bergi both I guess, I read and full MDN reduce() documentation and tried some of the programs but still not confident in using reduce method, any suggestions, please? Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest not to use it in this case. The accumulator stays the same, using `reduce` is kinda pointless here. Use a normal loop: `const acc = {}; for (const obj of objectArray) { … } return acc;`

Comment: @Bergi Okay, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reduce` is grouping by certain property.  This involves creating arrays in the object keyed by each grouping and pushing the items into the array.  If one particular item is the first member of its group encountered in the course of iterating, there will not yet be an array at the key to push to.  Thus--

```
if (!acc[key]) {
  acc[key] = []
}
```

-- checks to see if there is an array available yet at the key to push to.  If not, then it will add an array at the key for group members to be added to.  So, this `if` condition will only evaluate as `true` a single time for each group-- the very first time a member of the group is encountered.